# I would like to know, what is the difference between these two code samples. One works and the other does not

Tags: python, list

```
# This is Sample one and it does work. but it is long
n = [3, 5, 7]
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return(x)
print(double_list(n))

# This is sample two and it does not work.
n = [3, 5, 7]
def double_list(x):
    for i in x:
        i  = i * 2
    return(x)
print(double_list(n))
```

The codes above are meant to take the items of the list entered and then multiply each item of the list by two, then return the list.

I want to know, why does the one first one work, and why does to second one not work. The second one is shorter. The first one takes the index and then uses the index to call the item and then multiplys. but the second just directly multiplys the item. The second is more concise, then why does it not work?

Comment: the second one only modify the local copy of the x list elements

Comment: @PawełKordowski Observ `x[i] = x[i] * 2` and `i  = i * 2`

Comment: The second one just modifies the elements in the list without appending or saving the values to a new list, while the first one uses the index gotten from the range function to modify items in the list

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are accessing you list by using the

```
x[i] = x[i] * 2
```

So you use your local variable "i" to access the list element with the index i and then you change the content of it.

However in your second example you do not even access you list x, since you are only working with your local variable "i". Thus you do not change the list and the list remains unchanged. You can easily tell this, because if you were accessing your list, you would have written sth like

```
x[i] =
```

or

```
x =
```

If you have further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: In my second example, how am i not accessing the list? I wrote: for each item in the list of x: the item should be multiplied by two. When i multiplied the value by two, i saved it back in the same place of the original value. Im confused because i thougth that instead of accessing the items in the lsit by using the index of it, i thought i could just directly access the item because the for statement in the second example says: for each item in the list of x.......

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your code works with each elements of your list and change them:

```
x[i] = x[i] * 2
```

Your loop uses i for enumeration an one elements of list. And your multiply each element by two and rewrites each element of your list.

The second part of your code:

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
def double_list(x):
    for i in x:
        i  = i * 2
    return(x)
print(double_list(n))
```

each step of your loop creates copy of element and works with it. After that your loop returns existed x list... without any changing.